# Fix x and y dimension size regardless the sample data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset that was sampled from a 2-D area (100x100), and I want a scatter plot to show which points in this area are actually sampled. Yet, I am having difficulty to control the X Y axis. For example, suppose I only have three samples:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=c(1,3,5), y=c(6,7,2))) + geom_point()
```

The X, Y will only extend to maximum x=5, y=7 in this case, instead of a fixed dimension size of (100x100). I tried with:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=c(1,3,5), y=c(6,7,2))) + geom_point() +   
     scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1,100,1)) + scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(1,100,1))
```

but it doesn't seem to work. TIA

Comment: Add the limits=c(0,100) argument to the scale_x(y)_cont. functions

Comment: that seems did the trick. thanks, you want to post it as an answer so I can acknowledge to you?

Comment: Good stuff. easier for you to post an answer - you have the codes alr. cheers

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, user20650 provided the right answer: I can give `limit=c(0,100)` to scale functions, the complete drawing command would be:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=c(1,3,5), y=c(6,7,2))) + geom_point() +   
   scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1,100,1), limit=c(0,100)) +  
   scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(1,100,1), limit=c(0,100))
```